# Error opening a dictionary from an external json file

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, dictionary, anaconda

I wanted python to open my dictionary out of an external json file.

This is with python 3.7.2 in anaconda spyder on windows.

This is the written thing in my file:

```json
r{"0" : {"-25 : 144, 0 : 182, 25 : 224, 50 : 272"}}
r{"1000" : {"-25 : 157, 0 : 198, 25 : 245, 50 : 297"}}
r{"2000" : {"-25 : 172, 0 : 216, 25 : 267, 50 : 324"}}
r{"3000" : {"-25 : 188, 0 : 236, 25 : 292, 50 : 354"}}
r{"4000" : {"-25 : 205, 0 : 258, 25 : 319, 50 : 387"}}
r{"5000" : {"-25 : 224, 0 : 283, 25 : 349, 50 : 423"}}
r{"6000" : {"-25 : 246, 0 : 309, 25 : 381, 50 : 463"}}
r{"7000" : {"-25 : 269, 0 : 339, 25 : 418, 50 : 507"}}
r{"8000" : {"-25 : 295, 0 : 371, 25 : 458, 50 : 555"}}
r{"9000" : {"-25 : 323, 0 : 407, 25 : 502, 50 : 609"}}
r{"10000" : {"-25 : 354, 0 : 446, 25 : 551, 50 : 668"}}
```

I wanted to open my file with the following code:

```
togr650 = {}
with open("to_gr_650.json", "r") as config_file:
    togr650 = json.load(config_file)

print(togr650)
```

Unfortunatelly the following error appeard:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-29-098635d60a19>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Users/***/Desktop/take_off_distance.py', wdir='C:/Users/***/Desktop')

  File "C:\Users\***\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 827, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Users\***\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 110, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "C:/Users/***/Desktop/take_off_distance.py", line 26, in <module>
    togr650 = json.load(config_file)

  File "C:\Users\***\Anaconda3\lib\json\__init__.py", line 296, in load
    parse_constant=parse_constant, object_pairs_hook=object_pairs_hook, **kw)

  File "C:\Users\***\Anaconda3\lib\json\__init__.py", line 348, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)

  File "C:\Users\***\Anaconda3\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())

  File "C:\Users\***\Anaconda3\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None

JSONDecodeError: Expecting value
```

How do I have to change my code to let it work propperly?

Comment: That isn't JSON; it looks more like a string literal (though I would expect `r'{...}'` instead of `r{...}` in that case). Fix whatever is producing the JSON file so that it actually produces JSON.

Comment: Even without the leading r, this is not valid JSON. The nested element is a mixture of string (quotes) and object (curly braces). Whatever is producing that „JSON“ is what needs fixing.